# Resourses for reviewing writings

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources

I am looking for sites or communities where I can post my writings for reviews free of charge. Is there any?

Comment: [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com) or Language Learning.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com) might be more likely to have people who know of such resources.

Comment: @Mitch Requests for resources are not on-topic on the main ELL site. We do have some [alternative sites](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/9161) listed on [ell.meta.se]. Unfortunately, some site that offered free proof-reading in the past have shut down, so I'm not sure how up-to-date it is.

Comment: @ColleenV I'm well aware that resource requests are not on-topic on main and also very active in reminding everyone that they are very much _on-topic_ on meta (that is, they are very appropriate for ELU, just on meta, rather than just blankly saying 'off-topic'. As to the this particular request, all I'm saying is that there are more likely going to get good suggestions on sites dedicated to language learners, which ELU definitely is not. That said, I'm also sure that this is a duplicate on meta.ELU.

Comment: @Mitch but your link points to the main site instead of meta, which would be confusing for someone new.

Comment: @ColleenV oops. My fault. I didn't see it as ELL, and I also didn't know that about ELL. But anyway, if one were to order relevance of those three sites, whether main or meta, ELU would come last, don't you think?

Comment: @Mitch Resource requests aren't really on-topic at all on any site - it's just to be helpful that we entertain them at all on the meta sites. ELL is happy to get people learning English as a foreign language referred to us. I just would like to protect new users from getting a bad reception on their very first question, and they can't participate on Meta sites until they have 5 reputation. So, if we don't have a specific post to refer them to, we probably should make it clear that the question isn't on-topic on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

The only link I can find on ELU is [already in the Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and simply assists with searching for services. Because services might start up and shut down without warning, it's impractical to maintain a list on this site — unlike with online dictionaries, which have proved their longevity and are actually helpful to on-topic questions.

The link is to a Google search: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=online+proofreading+service